# Combine multiple left joins in 1 query

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries that I would like to combine. One query is left joining columns in the same table, the other query is left joining columns from two different tables. Both queries have the same table, just unsure how to properly set up the query.

1st Query:

```
SELECT BIZ_GROUP,
       ORDER_ID,
       STATION,
       A.TC_DATE,
       WANT_DATE,
       TIME_SLOT,
       JOB_CODE,
       [ADDRESS],
       CITY,
       A.TECH_ID,
       A.PREMISE,
       ISNULL(B.LAST_ARRIVED, A.LAST_ARRIVE) AS ARRIVED,
       ORDER_CLOSED,
       COMP_STATUS,
       WORK_STATUS,
       REMARKS,
       CORRECTION
FROM MET_timecommit A
     LEFT JOIN(SELECT premise,
                      TC_DATE,
                      TECH_ID,
                      MIN(last_arrive) AS LAST_ARRIVED
               FROM MET_timecommit
               WHERE PREMISE IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY premise,
                        TC_DATE,
                        TECH_ID) B ON B.TC_DATE = A.TC_DATE
                                  AND B.PREMISE = A.PREMISE
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MET_timecommit
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ORDER_ID,
                       created,
                       host_creation,
                       went_to 
                FROM workload
                WHERE went_to >= getdate()-365) C ON C.went_to=MET_timecommit.TC_DATE
                                                 AND C.order_id=MET_timecommit.order_id
```

***Evidently I am not used to this forum. You all don't have to be so rude. TDP was able to help me out based on what I provided. All other comments were unnecessary.***

Comment: How do you want to combine them ? Some sample data and a wanted result set would help.

Comment: We need a lot more detail here. You can't just slap a couple of random queries on a forum and expect somebody to magically understand what you want. You also should take a look at this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Some formatting would also help. Please don't put every column and your table on a single line; it makes things very difficult to read. Also, those queries on their own wouldn't have ran, there was a trailing parathensis on both of them. (Thus, are we missing some of the query here? I removed them both anyway.)

Comment: @SymoneColeman Help us help you.  How do you expect us to know what columns are in your table, and what column to use as join condition?  Learn how to ask question properly.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Evidently I am not used to this forum. You all don't have to be so rude. TDP was able to help me out based on what I provided. All other comments were unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should bring back the rows for both tables B and C for each row of table A:

```
SELECT A.BIZ_GROUP,
       A.ORDER_ID,
       A.STATION,
       A.TC_DATE,
       A.WANT_DATE,
       A.TIME_SLOT,
       A.JOB_CODE,
       A.[ADDRESS],
       A.CITY,
       A.TECH_ID,
       A.PREMISE,
       ISNULL(B.LAST_ARRIVED, A.LAST_ARRIVE) AS ARRIVED,
       A.ORDER_CLOSED,
       A.COMP_STATUS,
       A.WORK_STATUS,
       A.REMARKS,
       A.CORRECTION,
       C.*
FROM MET_timecommit A
     LEFT JOIN(SELECT premise,
                      TC_DATE,
                      TECH_ID,
                      MIN(last_arrive) AS LAST_ARRIVED
               FROM MET_timecommit
               WHERE PREMISE IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY premise,
                        TC_DATE,
                        TECH_ID) B ON B.TC_DATE = A.TC_DATE
                                  AND B.PREMISE = A.PREMISE
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ORDER_ID,
                       created,
                       host_creation,
                       went_to 
                FROM workload
                WHERE went_to >= getdate()-365) C ON C.went_to=A.MET_timecommit.TC_DATE
                                                 AND C.order_id=A.MET_timecommit.order_id
```